# Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value motivation

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Hi This firebase function use to work, but know its now longer working and I'm getting this error message

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

```
exports = module.exports = functions.analytics.event('first_open').onLog((event) => {
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'you have a new user \uD83D\uDE43',
      body: event.data.user.deviceInfo.mobileModelName + ' from ' + event.data.user.geoInfo.city + ', ' + event.data.user.geoInfo.country,
      sound:"default",
      vibrate:"true"
    },
  };
   admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
   admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);
```

to this:

```
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it before, the error message is gone but I'm still not receiving my notification

Comment: Nevermind is now working, my token number was wrong. I'll accept your answer Thank you

Comment: Hello john, would you mind helping me with this problem! Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979948/transfer-money-from-stripe-account-to-other-account

Answer (score 2):

In firebase functions, you should return a Promise or a value. You can return a value if your function is already finished. If your work has still has ongoing work you must return a Promise, which should be resolved once the work is done.

In your scenario, you have `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);` which is not finished at the end of the method. So you should return a promise which is resolved once the work is done. Luckily `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);` itself returns a promise. So you can just return it from the function as following.

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);
```