# Transfer money from stripe account to other account

Tags: ios, node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm using this to charge a connected account the send the money to another account but I keep getting this error message.

I keep getting this error message:

> You cannot supply a `destination` when charging a connected account.

```
   return stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 1000,
      currency: "usd",
      source: customer_id,
        destination: {
      account: "acct_1BxnsfGGXo2wovzm"
     },
 });
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message it seems the api believes you're using account debits where the destination parameter does not make sense:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits

So it's likely that your `customer_id` variable contains an account id instead of a customer id here.

Comment: Yes you are right, so in order for connected accounts to send money to each other. The account must also have a customer id right?!

Comment: Funds can only move between the platform and a connected account.